# Constructing base mesh for required subdivision surface

Tags: compression, subdivision

Given a triangle mesh, does there exist any algorithm to compute a base mesh (smaller in size than the triangle mesh) that could be subdivided multiple times to get back the original mesh (or an approximate of the original) ?

Thanks!